# Uploading a data url with finuploader

Tags: javascript, blob, fine-uploader

I'm currently creating some images using a few canvas libraries and I wanted possibly upload them via fineuploader.  I'm generating a blob and data url to display the previews.  Is there a way to submit this to the upload queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload any blob by submitting it to [Fine Uploader's `addFiles` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addFiles). For example:

`uploader.addFiles(blob)`

-or-

`uploader.addFiles({name: 'file name', blob: blob});`